# Plotting two functions with different sample rate

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot two functions: sin(x) and a sampled and quantized sin(x). The script is simple

```
set xtic 1
set ytic 1
f1(x) = sin(x/16*2*pi)*8
round(x) = x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? floor(x) : ceil(x)
plot [0:16] [-8.5:8.5] f1(x) with lines,  round(f1(x)) with steps lt 2
```

The problem is, I want the sin(x) to be smooth and the sampled an quantized sin(x) sampled at intervals of 1. The problem is, I can't find any option to do so. Adding

```
set sample 21
```

nearly works, but the sin(x) does not look smooth enough. Is there any way to make it better?

Comment: Try `plot [0:16] [-8.5:8.5] f1(x) with lines,  f1(round(x)+0.0) with steps lt 2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Round the variable of `f1()` not `f1()` itself and use `floor()` instead of `round()`

```
plot [0:16] [-8.5:8.5] f1(x) with lines,  f1(floor(x)+0.0) with steps lt 2
```

also, set a lot of samples to keep the quantized plot properly aligned:

```
set samples 1000
```

If you use `round()` instead of `floor` the quantization steps are "0.5 steps" (0.5 to 1.5, 1.5 to 2.5 etc) instead of "1 steps".

[image: floor]

[image: round]

Comment: This was it. To be exact: round(f1(floor(x)+0.0)), f1(floor(x)+0.0) will just make it sampled, the round is to make it quantized (a 4-bit quantizer in this case). Thanks.