# How to use floor function in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130656/plotting-two-functions-with-different-sample-rate) the OP defines the functions `round` with the function `floor` in `gnuplot`. Help for `floor` says:

```
gnuplot> help floor
 The `floor(x)` function returns the largest integer not greater than its
 argument.  For complex numbers, `floor` returns the largest integer not
 greater than the real part of its argument.
```

How can I use `floor` I did:

```
gnuplot> floor(7.3)
         ^
         invalid command
```

Can i somehow alter the number of decimal places to which number will be rounded to?

Comment: Please read the question you link again. The author defines his own `round` function as `round(x) = x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? floor(x) : ceil(x)`. And to test something with gnuplot you must do e.g. `print floor(7)`.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I will edit the question regarding usage of `floor`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check or print the result of a function call you must explicitely `print` it

```
gnuplot> print floor(7.3)
7
```

To modify the linked `round` function to round only at some decimal place, use the following

```
round(x) = x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? floor(x) : ceil(x)
round2(x, n) = round(x*10**n)*10.0**(-n)
```

and call it like

```
gnuplot> print round2(7.3456, 1)
7.3
gnuplot> print round2(7.3456, 2)
7.35
```